# plot bar chart with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create a bar chart with pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma] {
name,value
A,1
B,2
C,1
D,3
}\mytable
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    ybar,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=name,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\mytable}{name},
    ylabel=value
  ]
    \addplot table[x=name,y=value] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But got below error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'A' as a floating point number,
 sorry. The unreadable part was near 'A'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.26 ...\addplot table[x=name,y=value] {\mytable};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having tried a few things, like removing unused packages, specifying row sep etc, it turned out that:

- bar charts are 1-dimensional
- so you specify just one value

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=name,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\mytable}{name},    % <<<
        ylabel=value
      ]
    \addplot table[x=value] {\mytable}; % <<<
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

If you'd specify `y=value`, you'd get errors again:

```
    \addplot table[y=value] {\mytable};
```

Trying to read a column with names (characters) as values will result in an error:

```
\addplot table[x=name ...
```

[image: result]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705829/plot-bar-chart-with-pgfplots

\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=comma] {
    name,value\\
    A,1\\
    B,2\\
    C,1\\
    D,3\\
    }\mytable

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    ybar,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=name,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\mytable}{name},    % <<<
        ylabel=value
      ]
    \addplot table[x=value] {\mytable}; % <<<
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works without `row sep=\\\` and the `\\\` on each line. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18` is missing before `\begin{document}` to avoid the warning

Comment: what's the reason change it to x=value? actually I need y=value but x=name.

Comment: @lucky1928, try it and/or read my description in the answer. If you really need a xy-approach, i.e. place bars non-uniformly, you need a different approach.